# How to embed a Series into specific rows in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For instance, now I have a data frame df initially:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3])
df['B'] = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
df 
# A B
  1 a 
  1 b
  2 c
  2 d
  1 e
  3 f
  3 g
```

Now I'd like to replace the rows which column A equals to 1 with a list [0, 1, 2]. So, here is my expectation after embedding:

```
df 
# A B
  1 0 
  1 1
  2 c
  2 d
  1 2
  3 f
  3 g
```

How to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is the relation between the elements you are replacing and the element in column A ? For e.g. why are you replacing 0 in one instance, 1 in the second instance and so on for the same value of 1 in column A ? Is this sequential, so if there was another 1 in column A, do you want 4 or do you want to go back to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['A']==1, 'B'] = [0, 1, 2]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  2  c
3  2  d
4  1  2
5  3  f
6  3  g
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I check my code, and found the only difference is I use df.loc[df['A']==1, 'B'] = Series([0, 1, 2]). Why the output is different?

Comment: @0o0o0o0 `pd.Series` caries index with itself, so you will see on row `4` `NaN`. Just remove the `Series` and will work correctly.